# Connect desktop c# application to online mySql databse

Tags: c#, php, mysql, cpanel

I have a windows form application in C# and sometimes I want to push some data table from this application to an online `mySql` server which is hosting all data for my website in `PHP`. To do that I've installed :

1- `MySql` for visual studio version 1.2.3

2- `MySql` Connector.Net 6.9

Also, I have enabled Remote `MySql` on the server so I can make the connection. I used the '%' wildcard for the meantime because my IP address is dynamic.

my basic c# connection code is as below :

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "Server=*******;Database=*******;Uid=******;Pwd=********;";

        try
        {
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("connected successfully..");
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Unfortunately, every time I run this code I am getting an error which says
"Unable to connect to any of the specified `MySQL` hosts".
I don't' know where the problem is. Is it something on the UNIX server which
blocks the connections or some other thing which I need to do. I am also new to the CPanel interface and how to deal with it.

I appreciate all the help provided.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Did you see that? You can try it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the link talks about local connections where the database and the application are on the same server. In my case the mySql database is on an ONLINE server and I am trying to connect to it remotely from my c# desktop application.

Comment: It is same thing. All the way you will connect a server, it can be local or remote. Just change localhost opitons to real one.

Comment: I believe almost the same procedures applies for remote server but they are not exactly the same. That's why there's something called "Remote mySQL" and that's why I am getting a connection error. I want to hear if someone have done this successfully and what's missing in my work.

Comment: Maybe you set wrong your connection details. In my opinion you should take more details from your service provider.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue many years ago and the only way I could get it to work was to enable remote MySql on the server I was running. This basically means allowing remote connections to access the DB. This of course is very risky and poses a major security problem. You can limit connections from specific IPs, but in my opinion its best to have a local DB and then perhaps push updates to an online source somehow.